How to ignore LND on-chain reserve balance?
I have around 120.000 sat remaining on-chain balance in LND and want to sweep the wallet completely, as the node is about to be permanently shut down.
The reserved_balance_anchor_chan amount was previously at 100.000 sat (which is the maximum I believe). I managed to reduce it to 20.000 sat by manually using abandonchannel on a few pending force closures (which had zero local balance anyway, so it didn't matter).
LND now has zero pending/active channels and my config forbids new channel openings, which makes the reserve balance pointless. I have not found a way to completely ignore or deactivate it.
Attempting to use sendcoins results in the expected error:
[lncli] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = reserved wallet balance invalidated: transaction would leave insufficient funds for fee bumping anchor channel closings

Of course, abandoning 20.000 sat would not be a big deal, I'm just curious.
